# Questions regarding HTTP 404 Not Found

Tags: java, model-view-controller, path, java-web-start

I am currently working on A middle-size Java Web application using Netbeans & GlassFish. And everything was good until I placed all JSP fils into the folder called LoginOut, which I created it to store all specific JSP files to make my project succinct. But after I placed all JSP files into that folder, the problem came out. In detailed, the browser keeps telling me HTTP 404 Not Found. This is a very common error I believe. I put relevant screenshots below. By the way, when I put all JSP files outside LoginOut folder, my application works fine. I don't know where the error has occurred..(Here is code) [Project Fils Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR3tx.png)

```
        public User checkLogin(String email, String password) throws SQLException,
                ClassNotFoundException {
            
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? and password = ?";
            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            st.setString(1, email);
            st.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            
            User user = null;
            
            if (rs.next()) {
                user = new User();
                user.setFullName(rs.getString("fullname"));
                user.setEmail(email);
            }
            
            conn.close();
            return user;
        }
```

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Login Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="LoginServlet" method="POST">
                Email: <input type="text" name="email" ><br><br>
                Password: <input type="password" name="pass" ><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" ><br><br>
                <a href="index.jsp">Click here to go back.</a>
            </form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

```
    package controller.Servlet;

    import Dao.UserDao.UserDAO;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import static java.lang.System.out;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import model.User.User;

    @WebServlet("/Login")
    public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public LoginServlet() {
            super();
        }

        UserDAO userDao = new UserDAO();

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");

            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            String password = request.getParameter("pass");

            try {
                User user = userDao.checkLogin(email, password);
                String destPage = "Login.jsp";

                if (user != null) {
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                    session.setAttribute("user", user);
                    destPage = "home.jsp";
                } else {
                    String message = "Invalid email/password";
                    request.setAttribute("message", message);
                }

                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(destPage);
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);

            } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                throw new ServletException(ex);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include all code and error messages in your question as text, not as screenshots.  Use the [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63321869/edit) button to edit the question.

Comment: Also: 1) you haven't asked any questions about absolute and relative paths (!), and 2) the information you have provided is probably NOT enough to be able to work out what you have >>actually<< done and why your app is now broken.